# Thread safe random number/string generator for an OAuth nonce in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, ssis, script-component

I've been using an OAuthBase class found [HERE](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs) in my SSIS 2008 C# Script Components (.NET 3.5).

It's been working fine, but recently I've ran into the problem where if I execute multiple script components in the same Data Flow Task, using the GenerateNonce method in the above OAuthBase class, I end up with the same nonce (random number).

Here's an excerpt from the OAuthBase class that generates the nonce:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace OAuth {
 public class OAuthBase {

    ....snip......

    protected Random random = new Random();

    public virtual string GenerateNonce() {
        // Just a simple implementation of a random number between 123400 and 9999999
        return random.Next(123400, 9999999).ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

In each script component I'm using this C# code to initiate the class and generate a nonce:

```
        OAuthBase oAuth = new OAuthBase();
        string nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
```

From my searching around I think this is related to it not being thread safe?  I'm not totally sure.

I'm only able to run .NET 3.5 in SSIS 2008, so I know some of the newer stuff introduced in .NET 4.0 I can't use.

Any ideas on how I can either modify the OAuthBase class and/or my C# script component code?

Comment: This nonce has very few possible values. Even the threading bug aside it is not unique by any means.

Comment: @usr - thanks.  I was wondering about that.  Maybe I just do something like `return Guid.NewGuid.ToString();`?  I'm not totally sure how long my nonce can be (hitting Magento REST API).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create multiple instance of `OAuthBase` at the same time, it is entirely possible that the individual instance will have a `Random` instance with the same seed, which by default the seed is the current tick count.  So this means the individual instances of `Random` possibly have been created with the same seed.  Try making the `Random` instance static.  But since [`Random` is not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049467/is-c-sharp-random-number-generator-thread-safe).  You would need to protect access to it.

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
private static readonly object randLock = new object();

public virtual string GenerateNonce()
{
    lock (randLock)
    {
        // Just a simple implementation of a random number between 123400 and 9999999
        return random.Next(123400, 9999999).ToString();
    }
}

// since you had protected access on random, I'm assuming sub classes want to use it
// so you'll need to provide them with access to it
protected int NextRandom(...)
{
    lock (randLock)
    {
         random.Next(...);
    }
}
```

But as others have suggested since you don't have a cryptographically strong source of randomness, you may want to look at other ways to generate your value.

```
// RNGCryptoServiceProvider is thread safe in .NET 3.5 and above
// .NET 3.0 and below will need locking to protect access
private static readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider random =
    new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

public /*virtual*/ byte[] GenerateNonce(int length)
{
    // a default length could be specified instead of being parameterized
    var data = new byte[length];
    random.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
    return data;
}
// or
public /*virtual*/ string GenerateNonce(int length)
{
    var data = new byte[length];
    random.GetNonZeroBytes(data);        
    return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
}
```

Comment: Combine this with replacing Random with [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) like [usr said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14843988/80274) and you will have the perfect answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain updated to include an example using RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Comment: Just a fyi to everyone else in case they did not know, [RNGCryptoServiceProvider is  thread safe only for versions 3.5 and newer of .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#threadSafetyToggle), so if you are targeting 3.0 or older you still need to use a lock.

Comment: Just a note on how Base64 works, the length of the string generated from the last method will be 4/3 the length of the byte array passed in (`length`) (Remainders are rounded up and padded with `=` at the end)

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation on this.  One minor thing is the `random.GetNonZeroByte` should be `random.GetNonZeroBytes` (I tried to edit the answer but it wouldn't let me just add 2 's' to each method).

Comment: @JGinSD - if I create 2 'OAuthBase` objects at the same time from different threads, will each object have the same `random` object/value since it's being created at the time the `OAuthBase oAuth = new OAuthBase();` is being called?  `random` is only used in the `GenerateNonce` method, so would it be better if I just put that directly in the method? (sorry if I'm not making sense or using the wrong syntax...I'm a bit of a n00b still).

Comment: @jared If you marked the `random` member instance as **static** there will only ever be one random number generator, the number of threads creating an `OAuthBase` at the time won't matter.  If you created the instance of `Random` within the `GenerateNonce` method you still have the potential for the same problem, as then individual `Random` instances could possibly be created at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

This nonce has very few possible values. Even the threading bug aside it is not unique by any means. Use a cryptographically strong source of randomness (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx), output 16 bytes and base64 them. This takes care of all of that.