# Fastest, thread safe way to create crypto-random numbers in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, random, parallel-processing, cryptography

Noticed that the crypto-random number generator isn't thread safe when generating random numbers in parallel over multiple threads. The generator used is `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` and it appears to repeat long stretches of random bits (128 bits). The code to reproduce this is shown below.

Short of using a lock to guard access to the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` instance (which kills the whole speed point here), does anyone have a faster way to generator crypto-random numbers?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Caching;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParallelRandomness
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test();
            Console.Write("Serialized verion running ...  ");
            test.Run(false);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Parallelized verion running ...  ");
            test.Run(true);
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Done.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        private readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider _rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        private readonly byte[] _randomBytes = new byte[128 / 8];
        private int collisionCount = 0;
        private readonly object collisionCountLock  = new object();

        public void Run(bool parallel)
        {
            const int numOfRuns = 100000;
            const int startInclusive = 1;
            const int endExclusive = numOfRuns + startInclusive;
            if (parallel)
                Parallel.For(startInclusive, endExclusive, x => GenRandomByteArrays(x));
            else
            {
                for (var i = startInclusive; i < endExclusive; i++)
                    GenRandomByteArrays(i);
            }
        }

        private void GenRandomByteArrays(long instance)
        {
            _rng.GetBytes(_randomBytes);
            var randomString = Convert.ToBase64String(_randomBytes);
            var cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            if (cache.Contains(randomString))
            {
                // uh-oh!
                lock (collisionCountLock)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Instance {0}: Collision count={1}. key={2} already in cache. ", instance, ++collisionCount, randomString);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MemoryCache.Default.Add(randomString, true, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5));
                Console.Write(instance % 2 == 0 ? "\b-" : "\b|"); // poor man's activity indicator
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is C# Random Number Generator thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049467/is-c-sharp-random-number-generator-thread-safe)

Comment: (Some of) the answers to that question provide fast *and* thread-safe methods of generating random numbers.

Comment: The for `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` documentation explicitly states: "This type is thread safe."

Comment: @ObliviousSage: Actually that class in question (`Random`) is not even crypto-random, so it's thread-safety and performance is irrelevant.

Comment: Aren't you using the same array in multiple threads? That's obviously not safe even if the PRNG itself is safe.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Doh! Yeah, that's the problem! You want to put that as the answer so I can give credit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=net-5.0#thread-safety) for `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` states:

> This type is thread safe.

Your code doesn't demonstrate that `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is not thread-safe, since you use the same array in multiple threads. That array reuse is not thread-safe even if `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is.

Regarding performance I want to note that creating a new instance of `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is very cheap. The expensive part is the per-call overhead of `GetBytes`.

So if you have performance trouble, the first thing I'd try is asking for more data in one go and splitting it yourself. If that's still not enough, use a stream cipher seeded by the system CSPRNG.

Comment: By all means use a stream cypher to stretch initial entropy, but you **must** seed it with a crypto CSRNG, not the system PRNG which is not secure. Reseed regularly from the CSPRNG so you do not get toolong a run from the stream cypher. Crypto is as strong as its weakest link, and a non-crypto PRNG is weak.

Comment: @rossum By the system PRNG I mean `/dev/urandom` or `CryptGenRandom`. Not the crappy `System.Random` included with .net.