# Should I cache RNGCryptoServiceProvider/RandomNumberGenerator instances?

Tags: .net, performance, caching, random, cryptography

I've read lots of times about the efficiency of the `Regex` class and how important it is to either call it's static methods or cache the regex instance.

I'd like to know if the same problems would be observable if I instantiated the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class multiple times instead of caching a single instance of the class and calling `GetBytes` on it.

Instantiating it every time I need a random number would simplify my code a bit since I don't have to worry about a disposable instance hanging and propagating an `IDisposable` interface across a bunch of classes.

The only thing I found about this is that [creating an instance of a RNGCryptoServiceProvider should be very fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24046588/1946412), but I'd still like to see confirmation and what would the best practices be.

Would there also be any differences in the random numbers being generated if I instantiated the class every time versus using the same instance?

Comment: I'd really like to know why there are 2 votes to close the question.

Comment: "I'd really like to know why there are 2 votes to close the question." - because there are a lot of immature zealots on SO (sorry to the rest of you of which this does not apply). One of my [most up-voted questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24769701/264031) was one which I had to fight the zealots hard to even keep it open. Unbelievable. I think it gives these individuals a small taste of power which they can't resist exercising.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Repeated construction using the default constructor shouldn't have any ill effects for performance or randomness quality.

Let's take a look at the source code...

```
#if !FEATURE_PAL
        [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
        public RNGCryptoServiceProvider() : this((CspParameters) null) {} 
#else // !FEATURE_PAL
        public RNGCryptoServiceProvider() { } 
#endif // !FEATURE_PAL
```

The FEATURE_PAL directive has to do with windows vs. non-windows platforms. But we don't need to know the details; let's just look at both true and false cases.

First, it's clear that if FEATURE_PAL is enabled, there's no code in the default constructor.

In the other case, the constructor calls a specific constructor with null CspParameters. That other constructor looks like this:

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated 
public RNGCryptoServiceProvider(CspParameters cspParams) {
   if (cspParams != null) { 
         m_safeProvHandle = Utils.AcquireProvHandle(cspParams);
         m_ownsHandle = true;
   }
   else { 
         m_safeProvHandle = Utils.StaticProvHandle;
         m_ownsHandle = false; 
   } 
}
```

cspParams will always be null, so the constructor is getting the value of `Utils.StaticProvHandle`. That getter looks like this:

```
#if !FEATURE_PAL 
        [System.Security.SecurityCritical /*auto-generated*/] 
        private static SafeProvHandle _safeProvHandle = null;
        internal static SafeProvHandle StaticProvHandle { 
            [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
            get {
                if (_safeProvHandle == null) {
                    lock (InternalSyncObject) { 
                        if (_safeProvHandle == null) {
                            SafeProvHandle safeProvHandle = AcquireProvHandle(new CspParameters(DefaultRsaProviderType)); 
                            Thread.MemoryBarrier(); 
                            _safeProvHandle = safeProvHandle;
                        } 
                    }
                }
                return _safeProvHandle;
            } 
        }
#endif // !FEATURE_PAL
```

It's backed by a static variable. The getter uses some locks during first initialization, but subsequent calls simply return the static variable.

Now let's look back at RNGCryptoServiceProvider.cs and look at the Dispose method:

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
   base.Dispose(disposing);

   if (disposing && m_ownsHandle) {
         m_safeProvHandle.Dispose(); 
   } 
}
```

`m_ownsHandle` is false if the default constructor was called, so it never disposes anything.

So all that happens during each construction+disposal is some simple variable access.

Comment: Try and make "Repeated construction shouldn't have any ill effects for performance or randomness quality" the first statement is this response. Those interested can read the how. +1 for you.

Comment: feedback incorporated