# C# Different random functions both generating the same value

Tags: c#, random, methods

I'm developing a program that generates up to 2 valid IMEI codes at a time for mobile phone testing.
Although there is a method for each of the 2 codes, the program is always returning the same value for both (e.g. IMEI 1 = IMEI 2).
Here's a sample of both methods (only the relevant parts).

IMEI 1:

```
public String IMEICode()
    {
        int[] code = new int[14];
        Random generate = new Random();
        int format = FormatCombo.SelectedIndex;
        StringBuilder IMEI = new StringBuilder();
        ... //irrelevant
        for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
        {
            code[i] = generate.Next(10);
        }
        ... //irrelevant
        return IMEI.ToString();
    }
```

IMEI 2:

```
public String IMEICode2()
    {
        int[] code2 = new int[14];
        Random generate2 = new Random();
        int format = FormatCombo.SelectedIndex;
        StringBuilder IMEI2 = new StringBuilder();
        ... //irrelevant
        for (int i = 0; i < code2.Length; i++)
        {
            code2[i] = generate2.Next(10);
        }
        ... //irrelevant
        return IMEI2.ToString();
    }
```

The program has 2 text boxes to display the generated codes (Field1 and Field2), each assigned to a method (IMEICode() and IMEICode2()).

PS.: I made sure that the first text box displays the IMEICode() method and the latter displays the IMEICode2() method.

Comment: Use same `Random` object for both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different `Random` objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have **identical default seed values** and, therefore, **will produce identical sets of random numbers**. This problem can be avoided by **using a single Random object** to generate all random numbers. You can also work around it by modifying the seed value returned by the system clock and then explicitly providing this new seed value to the `Random(Int32)` constructor. (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx))

Use same `Random` object for both cases.

```
    public static Random generate = new Random();

    public String IMEICode()
        {
            int[] code = new int[14];
            int format = FormatCombo.SelectedIndex;
            StringBuilder IMEI = new StringBuilder();
            ... //irrelevant
            for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
            {
                code[i] = generate.Next(10);
            }
            ... //irrelevant
            return IMEI.ToString();
        }

    public String IMEICode2()
        {
            int[] code2 = new int[14];
            int format = FormatCombo.SelectedIndex;
            StringBuilder IMEI2 = new StringBuilder();
            ... //irrelevant
            for (int i = 0; i < code2.Length; i++)
            {
                code2[i] = generate2.Next(10);
            }
            ... //irrelevant
            return IMEI2.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: `Random` class is not thread-safe, so you are treading on thin ice here by relying on the threading nature of the test runner. Better using `ThreadLocal<Random>` instead.

Comment: More info in thread safety and random at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049467/is-c-sharp-random-number-generator-thread-safe