# Issue with Random string generator producing identical results

Tags: c#-4.0, random

I use a random string generator, based on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-8-character-alphanumeric-strings-in-c

Every now and then, it will generate a 20 chars len string like this
**aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa** when it needs to generate a 20 chars len string full of random chars (eg **63TSRVvbVDJiMNwneB5l**), like if the C# Random object would return a value of 0 every time over the 20 iterations.

```
public static string GetRandomAlphaNumericString(int charCount)
{
  var result = new string(
      Enumerable.Repeat(CHARS, charCount)
                .Select(s =>
                {
                  var nxt = SHARED_RANDOM.Next(s.Length);
                  var rval = s[nxt];

                  return rval;
                })
                .ToArray());
  return result;
}

const string CHARS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

public static Random SHARED_RANDOM = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

It doesn't make sense to me, what could I be overseeing in this generator ? The generator works OK, but every now and then, very rarely, it would perform like this generating a strike aaaaaaa strings for a short period of time.

I don't see a bug in the code, so to me it's 1 of 2 things, or the C# Random object is acting funny in some situations, returning 0 for a short period of time, or the CHARS const string changes from "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" to "a" in the assembly for some reason, for a short period of time.

I can't believe it could be either of the above, I prefer to believe that I'm overseeing something. Do you see or imagine how could this possibly be happening ?

### UPDATE OCT 23 / 2017

Coded a test routine so if the **GetRandomAlphaNumericString** produces the evil **aaaaa** string, it will throw an error, but logs a quick report before.

The report generates 3 random numbers in a row, and adds it to the log:

```
    SHARED_RANDOM.Next(20);
    SHARED_RANDOM.Next(20);
    SHARED_RANDOM.Next(20);
```

The 3 numbers produced are 0, nice uh ?

This tells me that the issue is not the **GetRandomAlphaNumericString**, but the Random object itself. 
There is some sort of corruption that causes the object to return those results, so basically it could be anything ?!

Comment: i believe its because of your static Random variable change it and it  may work

Comment: Does your application have multithreading?  `Random` is not thread-safe.

Comment: For other readers - OP found the solution to his question at this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3049467/314291). TL;DR; - by sharing a static `Random` across multiple threads, the RNG can break causing it to return 0. Random isn't thread safe.