# Hygienic way of sharing one Random in entire application

Tags: c#, random

If you use `System.Random` all over the place, is there a hygienic way of making sure that it's an app-wide singleton? I've though of several options, including the following:

- Global static member -- this has the unfortunate effect of having to call `SomeClass.Random.Next()`. This can be mitigated with `using static` but the approach doesn't really scale since you have to do this everywhere.
- Derived singleton -- simply deriving from `Random` (it's not `sealed`!) and making that class a lazy thread-safe singleton
- Register a random in DI as a singleton and inject -- but injecting a `Random` into every class is really tedious

Ideally I just want to call some `rand()` in *any* class and have all of them refer to a single instance.

Comment: Multi-threading safe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049467/is-c-sharp-random-number-generator-thread-safe, single-threaded - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk You could just create a [custom snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio to insert something like `using static SomeNamespace.SomeClass;`, then use a shortcut of, say, "rnd" so you could just type "rnd" and press tab twice to insert it. Not ideal, but saves a lot of typing.

Answer (score 3):

> this has the unfortunate effect of having to call `SomeClass.Random.Next()`

no it doesn't: consider a type like:

```cs
internal static class Foo
{
    private static readonly Random s_random = new Random();
    // todo: any thread safety concerns
    public static int Rand() => s_random.Next();
    public static int Rand(int minValue, int maxValue) => s_random.Next(minValue, maxValue);
}
```

Now you can add `using static Declaration.Foo;` at the top of a file that wants to use it, and *now* you can just use `Rand()` without anything else.

Comment: But now imagine 50 classes using this, and having each class with a `using static` is not economical.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk I don't buy that argument; it is no less economical than `using`, which we wouldn't care about being repeated in those same 50 files

Comment: @MarkGravell the difference is your IDE will insert a `using` for you, wheras no IDE will help you with `using static`