# How to implement a thread-safe random

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, random, cryptography

Trying to find and understand the best approach to implement a thread-safe number generator in .NET Core 2.x or higher

First Iv'e found this -
https://web.archive.org/web/20160326010328/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx

After reading through it seems to me like there are couple of "good" ways -

1. ThreadStatic Random instance, with a global random instance to generate seeds
2. ThreadStatic Random instance, with a global RNGCryptoServiceProvider to generate seeds

Where basically you choose the latter if a strong cryptographically random is a requirement.

After some additional research I found out that since .NET Core 2.x System.Random class was revised, therefore the default seed generation which is no longer primary dependent on the system timer.
(https://blogs.siliconorchid.com/post/coding-inspiration/randomness-in-dotnet)

Question -
How does this affect the implementation of a thread-safe random class?

Refrencing the first link Iv'e shared code solution -

```cs
public static class RandomGen2
{
    private static Random _global = new Random();
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Random _local;

    public static int Next()
    {
        Random inst = _local;
        if (inst == null)
        {
            int seed;
            lock (_global) seed = _global.Next();
            _local = inst = new Random(seed);
        }
        return inst.Next();
    }
}
```

Since dotnet core 2.x adjustments is a global locked seed generator even required? or a basic ThreadStatic random instance is all thats needed? such as -

```cs
    public static class ThreadSafeRandom
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static Random _local;

        public static int Next()
        {
            Random inst = _local;
            if (inst == null)
            {
                _local = inst = new Random();
            }
            return inst.Next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your question related to this? [Is C# Random Number Generator thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049467/is-c-sharp-random-number-generator-thread-safe)

Comment: Yes it is related, this is where I found the first article iv'e shared in my question.
But as this answer is 10 years-old, and since then dotnet has revisted System.Random Iv'e tried looking for a more up to date solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From .NET 6 you can use `Random.Shared` to get a thread-safe instance of `Random`.

The documents say this:

> Provides a thread-safe Random instance that may be used concurrently from any thread.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared?view=net-6.0

There's no need to get fancy anymore.

To get a random integer you just need to do:

```
int number = Random.Shared.Next();
```

---

If you want cryptographically strong randomness, then Eric Lippert's `BetterRandom` is the way to go:

```
public static class BetterRandom
{
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator> crng = new ThreadLocal<System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator>(System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create);
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<byte[]> bytes = new ThreadLocal<byte[]>(() => new byte[sizeof(int)]);
    public static int NextInt()
    {
        crng.Value.GetBytes(bytes.Value);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes.Value, 0) & int.MaxValue;
    }
    public static double NextDouble()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            long x = NextInt() & 0x001FFFFF;
            x <<= 31;
            x |= (long)NextInt();
            double n = x;
            const double d = 1L << 52;
            double q = n / d;
            if (q != 1.0)
                return q;
        }
    }
}
```

Start here to read more: https://ericlippert.com/2019/01/31/fixing-random-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the info!
So if a cryptographically strong randomness isn't a requirement and Im still not using .NET 6, I simply need a static instance of ThreadLocal Random and Im good to go? no additional code is required?

Comment: @Ben - That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. The algorithm the `System.Random` class use when instantiated with default constructor has changed to the new one, but the class is still not thread-safe, so old technique like using `[ThreadStatic]` is still needed.
2. In .NET Core, [the default seed value is produced by the thread-static, pseudo-random number generator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0#instantiating-the-random-number-generator) That means you don't need to implement global seed generator anymore.
3. Use `RandomNumberGenerator` when you really want to make sure your random number is secure. For example, if you just want to display random daily messages, use `System.Random`, but if you want to generate a random secret string, use `RandomNumberGenerator`.

Comment: Ty for the answer.
Updated my initial question with code samples, can you take a look? ty

Comment: It is ok for me as it should work correctly, but you might also use a static `ThreadLocal<Random>`, which will initiate Random instance for each thread for you so you don't need to do lazy instantiation by yourself like that.