# C#: state of a static member variable `Random` inside an instantiable object class

Tags: c#, random, static, static-methods

---

- As of 2022. May. 1

For someone who's encountered this question,
please check

[Is C# Random Number Generator thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049467/is-c-sharp-random-number-generator-thread-safe)

as I believe the answer there is useful.

---

Consider the following code example.
I have a class `Randomiser` that has a static member variable `public static Random rand`. I can instantiate the `Randomiser` object as many times as I want, while I can access the member variable `public static Random rand` at any scope. At each time I call `rand.Next()`, I expect that the variable `rand` changes its status. In particular, I can call `rand.Next()` in multiple threads as in the example code.

Because the `Random rand` is a static variable, any call of `rand.Next()` method will refer to the same memory stack, and it is supposed to use the same random states. This does not have any issue if `rand.Next()` is called in a single process as they will be executed in a sequential order and the random state is not mixed up. However, when multiple threads are invoking the `rand.Next()` method, and if they happen to call it exactly at the same time, if this is somehow possible, it is unclear how the random state should change; `rand.Next()` is not only a read-access but it also changes the random state.

It appears to be a very theoretical and even weird question, but is there anyone who can imagine what is going to happen to the `Random rand`'s random state when multiple threads are invoking at identical CPU clock?

```
    class Randomiser
    {
        public static Random rand = new 
                      Random(DateTime.UtcNow.GetHashCode());
                  
        public Randomiser(in string _name_) { this.name = _name_; }

        public string name = "";
        public int    num = -1;
    }
    class Program
    {   
        static void Main()
        {
            Randomiser[] Guys = 
            { 
                new Randomiser("Charlie"), 
                new Randomiser("Fox")
            };

            double for_ = 0.1;
            bool run = true;
            var t0 = DateTime.UtcNow;   
            
            new Thread(()=>
            { 
                while(run) 
                { 
                    Guys[0].num = Randomiser.rand.Next(); 
                    Console.WriteLine($"{Guys[0].name}: {Guys[0].num}");
                } 

            }).Start();

            new Thread(()=>
            { 
                while(run) 
                { 
                    Guys[1].num = Randomiser.rand.Next(); 
                    Console.WriteLine($"{Guys[1].name}: {Guys[1].num}");
                } 

            }).Start();
            
            while (true)
            {
                if ((DateTime.UtcNow - t0).TotalSeconds > for_)
                {
                    run = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: The answer is `Random.Next()` is not thread safe.

Comment: *It appears to be a very theoretical and even weird question* - up to that point you haven't actually asked a question. The only question you've actually even ended up asking is "can anyone imagine how..", the answer to which is "yes". Please collect your thoughts and refine your question

Comment: @CaiusJard Netmage has given a reasonable answer, and I found that one of the answers in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049467/is-c-sharp-random-number-generator-thread-safe" helps to understand what happens and how to improve potential problems. 

It seems you always 100% clearly know what you want to know and one is supposed not to have a very theoretical question nor have a weird question. Lucky you. Isn't that so strange many people already thought about similar concerns and have some idea how to handle it?