# Random.Next() generates same value forever. in Paralled.Foreachasync

Tags: c#, random, .net-7.0

I create a Random object at the start of my method. Then in that method I run a Parallel.Foreachasync loop.

Inside this I generate 2 random numbers using Random.Next(). I then check to see if the numbers are the different in a while loop. In the while loop I generate a new random number
until they are different. For the first few thousand loops this works fine. Then suddenly it gets stuck generating the same number over and over again...

```
var room1Index = rnd.Next(0, slot1.RoomList.Count - 1);
var room2Index = rnd.Next(0, slot2.RoomList.Count - 1);

while (room1Index == room2Index)
{
    room2Index = rnd.Next(0, slot2.RoomList.Count - 1);
}
```

I have checked the roomlist count and it is 4 so I would expect the two numbers to be different at least after a few iterations... However it always generates 0

Why could this be happening?

Comment: See [Is C# Random Number Generator thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3049467).  Answer: no.  Does using [`Random.Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared?view=net-7.0) as mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73655925) by Evgeny as well as Mark Cilia Vincenti's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77765988/3744182) to your question resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`Random.Next` is not thread-safe. You should use `Random.Shared.Next` on .NET 6+, or use [some library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ThreadSafeRandomizer) (disclaimer: am the author of this library) that solves a headache for you if you're not.

Comment: When offering your own library, it's a [good practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229091) to make it clear that it's yours (even if it turns out eventually when you open the link). _Example:_ Or you can use the [`ThreadSafeRandom.Instance`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/P_KGySoft_CoreLibraries_ThreadSafeRandom_Instance.htm) property from [this library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries) (disclaimer: I am the author).

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg took your advice and edited post