# How do I use random numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, random, xna

I'm working on Pong in C# w/ XNA.

I want to use a random number (within a range) to determine things such as whether or not the ball rebounds straight, or at an angle, and how fast the ball moves when it hits a paddle.

I want to know how to implement it.

Comment: Shouldn't the angle and speed be determined by how the ball hits the paddle? If you make it random, it seems your users would have a hard time anticipating where the ball is going.

Comment: @Esteban Not if it's Xtreme Pong!

Comment: In it's present state, the ball rebounds depending on whether or not the paddle is moving when it hits. But if neither paddle moved, the ball would go straight with no variation. I wanted to use a random number to change the angle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class.  For example:

```
Random r = new Random();
int nextValue = r.Next(0, 100); // Returns a random number from 0-99
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you should only create a *single instance* of Random (per thread). For simple, single-threaded games, making it a `public static readonly` member of the derived Game class is what I usually do. See also Jon Skeet's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217651/how-do-i-use-random-numbers-in-c/3218084#3218084

Answer (score 8):

Unless you need cryptographically secure numbers, [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) should be fine for you... but there are two gotchas to be aware of:

- You shouldn't create a new instance every time you need one. If you create an instance without specifying a seed, it will use the current time as the seed - which means if you create several instances in quick succession, many of them will produce the same sequence of numbers. Typically you create a long-lasting instance of `Random` and reuse it.
- It's not thread-safe. If you need to generate random numbers from multiple threads, you should think about having one instance per thread. Read [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx) for more information - but make sure you read the comments as well, as they have very useful information.

Comment: +1. Excellent tips; I've seen people get bitten by those time and time again. My favorite is mistake w/ Random is when people instantiate it inside a tight loop and seed it w/ `DateTime.Now` hoping that that will fix the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
rnd.Next(minValue, maxValue);
```

**i.e.**

```
rnd.Next(1,10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Random object's [Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) method that takes a min and max and returns a value in that range:

```
var random = new Random();    
int randomNum = random.Next(min, max);
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can use the `Random` class like all the other are suggesting, the `Random` class only uses psuedo-random number generation. The `RandomNumberGenerator`, which can be found in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace, creates actual random numbers.

How To Use:

```
RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
byte[] rand = new byte[25]; //Set the length of this array to
                           // the number of random numbers you want
rng.GetBytes(rand);
```

More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: RandomNumberGenerator is an abstract class. :) Use the RNGCryptoServiceProvider which derives from this class. Nevertheless it still produces "cryptographically strong" random numbers, which is still pseudo random. 
And according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418817/pros-and-cons-of-rngcryptoserviceprovider, RNGCryptoServiceProvider is slower and overkill for this matter.

Comment: This will be more random but may have a performance hit, so balance accordingly.  You may not need this amount of randomness and it also might not be quite as easy to use as Random

Comment: I thought I'd just through it out there as an option. To be honest, I probably just use Random as well.

Comment: `RandomNumberGenerator` doesn't generate "actual" random numbers; it's still a PRNG. The numbers generated by `Random` are fine if all you need is stochastic randomness. A cryptographic PRNG just generates numbers that are far harder to predict.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my random generator

```
 private static Random rnd = new Random(Environment.TickCount);

 private int RandomNum(int Lower, int Upper)
{

 return rnd.Next(Lower, Upper);//MyRandomNumber;

}
```